# Is it possible to wrap long lines in the GitHub diff viewer?

Tags: github

Is it possible to wrap long lines in the GitHub diff viewer?

Maybe a query string param?

Comment: Not that I know of. The only query string param I know of is adding `?w=1` to the URL to see the diff with whitespace ignored. Try asking GitHub Support.

Comment: If you change your GitHub preferences to show split diffs rather than unified diffs, the UI will always wrap long lines in split-diff views — though even for code, not just for text and markdown and HTML. You can use the gear icon in the UI of the **Commits** tab and **Files changed** tab to toggle the split/unified diff setting. But note that it’s a persistent setting that gets applied across all repos — there’s no way to set it per-repo or per-file-type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that from December 3rd, 2013, GitHub now proposes "[**Soft-wrapping on prose diffs**](https://github.com/blog/1707-soft-wrapping-on-prose-diffs)":
(Meaning you might not have to put anything special in the url or as a query to benefit from that feature)

Before:

[image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/173/1657839/1764c242-5b8a-11e3-82b7-f3409cc20f89.png]

After:

[image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/173/1657812/d3fab2be-5b89-11e3-83b5-ececcbe52158.png]

See as [an example a diff on a patch I did](https://github.com/VonC/reveal.js/compare/dev...attributes), where you can see the line soft-wrapped.