# Wrap long line of HTML doc in GitHub diff viewer?

Tags: html, github, word-wrap

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20369634/3046255) to a similar question mentions [a recent feature addition](https://github.com/blog/1707-soft-wrapping-on-prose-diffs) that enables soft-wrapping for "prose".  It seems that "prose" means markdown files. Anyone know **how to enable wrapping for HTML documentation diffs?**

Comment: If you change your GitHub preferences to show split diffs rather than unified diffs, the UI will always wrap long lines in split-diff views — though even for code, not just for text and markdown and HTML. You can use the gear icon in the UI of the **Commits** tab and **Files changed** tab to toggle the split/unified diff setting. But note that it’s a persistent setting that gets applied across all repos — there’s no way to set it per-repo or per-file-type.

Answer (score 2):

While GitHub has [soft-wrapping on prose diffs](https://github.com/blog/1707-soft-wrapping-on-prose-diffs), there is no current support for auto-wrapping of HTML. GitHub support responded:

> This is not possible currently, but we might add it in the future. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll add it to the Feature Request List™ so the team can see it.

Looking forward to seeing this feature. I don't know if they have community voting set up for features.